# Figuring out a voiceState change within an individual user in Discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

```
client.on('message', async message => {

    const voiceChannel = message.member.voice.channel;
    let user = message.mentions.users.first();
    let cleanMessage = message.content.toLowerCase();

    // starts by checking if message contains valid content
    if (!cleanMessage.match(start) && !cleanMessage.startsWith('quit') && !user) return;

    // join case
    if (cleanMessage.match(start) && user && voiceChannel) {

        console.log('connected!');
        
        voiceChannel.join()
        .then(connection => {

            connection.on('speaking', (user, speaking) => {
                if(user && speaking) {
                    dispatch = connection.play(fs.createReadStream(require("path").join(__dirname, './shush.webm')), { type: 'webm/opus'});
                    console.log(user);
                }
            })

            console.log(`${user.username} shushed!`);
            setTimeout(() => { voiceChannel.leave() }, 10000);

        }).catch(err => console.log(err));

        message.channel.send(`${user.username} shut up.`);
    }
```

Creating a bot and trying to figure out when an individual mentioned user is speaking, playing an audio upon the voiceState change. currently plays the audio if it detects a voicestate change in any user within the channel, rather than an individual mentioned user, unable to figure out exactly why. Console logs a new user every time somebody new speaks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your structure is well done, though the `if(user && speaking)` can be fixed easily. You are calling the variable "user" at the beginning of the 'speaking' function, although you have already stated the variable user in the past `let user = message.mentions.users.first();`, to achieve the outcome you expect you should start by removing the "user" variable from this line `connection.on('speaking', (user, speaking) => {` and replace `if(user && speaking) {` with `if(user === speaking)`.
The difference is that now you would be saying "If the user mentioned is speaking", then you would be able to trigger an outcome.

I hope this was helpful!